# The meaning of registered with someone?

Tags: phrases, british-english

It hadn’t properly registered yet with Arthur that the council wanted to knock it down" - what's the meaning of register with someone here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this: It hadn't sunk in yet.  Arthur had not come to accept reality.

Answer (score 0):

There is a definition for this use of 'register' in the [Merriam-Webster Learner's dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/register)

> **4 a [no object] : to be recognized or remembered**
>
> It took a moment for what she was saying to register. [=it took a
>   moment before I understood what she was saying]
>
> — often used in negative statements The name didn't register with me.
>   [=I didn't recognize the name]